# Heroku collaborators control Dynos?

Tags: heroku

The Heroku documentation states: 
"While only the app owner can change resources (dynos, workers, and add-ons), collaborators on an app can do pretty much anything else they'd like – push ..."

That sounds sensible.
So I've just added a collaborator to my Heroku app, but by chance I realized that the collaborator actually has full access to change the resources - meaning they can easily crank up the dynos and make me a huge bill.

How do I change the privileges for collaborators?

Comment: Can you link the docs you reference?

Answer (score 1):

At this time you cannot change collaborator privileges.

From "[Collaborator Privileges](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing#collaborator-privileges)":

> All actions are supported for collaborators as they are for app owners
>   except:
>
> - Adding or removing paid add-ons
> - Deleting or renaming the app
> - Viewing invoices